# How to make my self hosted GitHub runner run jobs in a docker container instead of the native shell and OS?

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I registered my Raspberry Pi 4 as a self hosted runner for GitHub. It works but all the jobs are run on the native system itself. How can I make GitHub also create a Docker container on the runner so that the underlying system remains clean? It default behaviour for GitLab I'm surprised its not for GiHub or maybe Im missing something pls help me.

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI Rasp

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: self-hosted

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run blinky for 3 times
        run: /home/jbron/blinky.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to achieve the same using the `container` context.

I believe it would look something like this:

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI Rasp

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container:
      # Runner docker image
      image: ubuntu:22.04

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run blinky for 3 times
        run: /home/jbron/blinky.py
```

Check this link for more info:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer

Comment: I see, i cannot try it out right now. But my question is. Do I need a hosted runner for that? Can it be some other publicly accessible docker container from dockerhub or just a set of popular ones that github specifies like ubuntu etc @Ger

Comment: I believe you could use any docker image for ``image``, however, the entrypoint I guess it should be something like ``bin/bash``.